# What is .clone().json() for in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an API call in my code and the data is stored like this

`const json = await data.clone().json();`

So my question is what is the difference between this and simply doing `const json = await data.json()`

Comment: It depends entirely on what `data` is.

Comment: @derpirscher Are you sure? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone

Comment: @Terry I stand corrected ...

Answer (score 2):

A `fetch` `Response` can only be read once. However, by creating a [`clone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone) you can create a new copy. That copy can itself only be read once, but after doing this clone then the original stream is still intact and can be read.